# How to show the remaining work of a bug in the sprint backlog

Tags: .net, tfs, tfs-2015

In our productbacklog the remaining work for the bug work item isn't displayed. It is also not summed up to the overall remaining time.

[image: backlog_image]

I've checked the WIT for Bug and it seems ok to me. I assume that TFS get the value by refname?!

```
<FIELD name="Verbleibende Arbeit" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" type="Double" reportable="measure" formula="sum">
    <HELPTEXT>An estimate of the number of units of work remaining to complete this task</HELPTEXT>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD name="Ursprüngliche Schätzung" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate" type="Double" reportable="measure" formula="sum">
    <HELPTEXT>Initial value for Remaining Work - set once, when work begins</HELPTEXT>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD name="Abgeschlossene Arbeit" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork" type="Double" reportable="measure" formula="sum">
    <HELPTEXT>The number of units of work that have been spent on this task</HELPTEXT>
  </FIELD>
```

If I create a query the remaining work is shown in the results
[image: query_image]

Any suggestions how the value can be displayed in the backlog and is also shown in the work details?

PS: We using somehow a modified version of the scrum process template.

Thanks in advance
Mat

Comment: How did you customize your work item type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this issue... it was actually quit simple. I will post my solution, maybe someone will find it useful.

You have to change the "Working with bugs" settings as follows:
[image]

Then the information shows up correct in the backlog.

[image]

Further information:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/show-bugs-on-backlog

Answer (score 0):

During the sprint, you can see a roll-up of the remaining work required to complete each requirement or bug, if you choose **Bugs appear on the backlogs and boards with requirements**.

[image]

As an alternative, you can choose **Bugs appear on the backlogs and boards with tasks**. In this way, you can see the remaining work for Bug work item.

Comment: thanks for your answer. In general we make no Tasks for bugs (senseless "fix bug" work items). Therefore it can also not roll up because a bug has no child items. I posted an answer which solved it with a "standard" bug without subitems -> I've found the same solution you suggested. ;-)